# Problem with Opening Tensorboard in Github for windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, github

I am using Github for windows and I have installed Anaconda and tensorflow. I would like to open Tensorboard. Following https://itnext.io/how-to-use-tensorboard-5d82f8654496, I type

```
tensorboard --logdir="./graphs"
```

But there is nothing prompt out except the message
"TensorBoard 1.12.2 at http://DESKTOP-VSHNRU0:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to open browser and go to http://DESKTOP-VSHNRU0:6006 web page? And maybe even better http://localhost:6006?

Answer (score 0):

In my case in Anaconda Terminal:

```
conda activate "your Tensorflow Environment with the installed Tensorboard"

python -m tensorboard.main --logdir=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\TensorFlow\workspace\training_demo\training
```

Then, open `http://localhost:6006/#scalars` in your Browser.